# Django query for a related object

Tags: django, querying, reverse-lookup

I have two models Post and UserBookmarks.

models.py of Project/App1

```
from App2 import UserBookmarks

class Post(models.Model):
        id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Title", max_length=20)
        content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Post Content", max_length=2000)
        ...
        bookmarks = GenericRelation(UserBookmarks, related_query_name='post')
```

models.py of Project/App2

```
bookmarkable_models = models.Q(app_label='App', model='post') | models.Q(app_label='App', model='model-b') | models.Q(app_label='App', model='model-c')

class UserBookmarks(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=bookmarkable_models, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False)
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
```

Now I want to check if the user has already added the post to his bookmarks as my views.py but I don't understand how my query for this has to look like. Currently im doing something like this:

```
def post_add_bookmark(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if post.bookmarks.filter(user=request.user).exists():
            messages.error(request,
                           'You already added this Post to your Bookmarks')
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
        else:
            post.bookmarks.create(user=request.user, object_id=post.pk)
            messages.success(request, 'Post has been added to your Bookmarks')
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Something went wrong')
        return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
```

Can smb. explain to me how this query has to look like in order to check if its already existing or not.
currently im getting the following error:

> Cannot query "peter123": Must be "UserBookmarks" instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the `post` is already bookmarked by the user with:

```
post.bookmarks.filter(user=request.user).exists()
```

It might however be a good idea to enforce this at the database level, such that it is simply impossible to store the same bookmark for the same user:

```
class UserBookmarks(models.Model):
    # …

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user, content_type', 'object_id'], name='unique_bookmark')
        ]
```

or prior to [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2):

```
class UserBookmarks(models.Model):
    # …

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['user, content_type', 'object_id']]
```

Comment: I updated my questions views.py accordingly. With your solution it seems I can add the same post x times as bookmark. Seems that the whole if statement is not checked for some reason

Comment: Even with your updated answere im running into an issue: App2.UserBookmarks: (models.E012) 'unique_together' refers to the nonexistent field 'user, content_type'.
So i changed your syntax to: unique_together = ('user', 'content_type', 'object_id') wich also again runs into the following execption:App2_userbookmarks` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")')

Comment: unique_together = [['user', 'content_type', 'object_id']] get the migration to work but still has no effect

Comment: @MarkusBrede: well then likely you use another `user`, `object_id`, or `content_type`. The `unique_together` is after all enforced at the *database* side. It will raise an `INTEGRITY ERROR`, if you try to create a second record with the same `user`, `object_id`, and `content_type`. So it looks to me that your view works with a different user, post primary key, etc.

Comment: I dont get the point on this as user == request.user so i should only be possible that i'm accessing the requesting user. I will try to build my function from scratch.

Comment: @MarkusBrede: can you see in the database a `UserBookmarks` item with as `content_type_id` the content type of `Post`, with `user` the primary key of the `peter123`, and with `object_id`, the primary key of the `Post` object you aim to bookmark?

Comment: I just check the database and there is a new object after I trigger my post_add_bookmark function and for each time I trigger it, a new bookmark object gets created. So I can indeed create unlimited bookmark objects for the same thing. Im on django 3.0.4 if that matters

Comment: Okay i Just found the mistake. So damn stupid. As django internaly query for object_id to establish the actuall reverse query and my object_id field is in practice encrypted, django was not able to accomplish the reverse lookup as it was always returning a different cryptographic key for each entry, fail. I first tought that I ran totaly transparent here with my encryption but it seems that my lib in background does not accomplish this for reverse lookups. Thank you very much for your help, again!

Comment: please update to answere to the correct syntax: unique_together = [['user', 'content_type', 'object_id']]. You are missing some quotes here